# 2-Dimensional Array for loop accessing element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a web application that uses JavaScript technology and how do i access a certain element after pushing

```
var items = [
  [Willy wunka, M, 10, Married]
];
```

I'm having a `for` loop which retrieves data from firebase. This is my code:

```
for(var key in data){
    var name = data[key].revieweeID.firstname.concat(" ",data[key].revieweeID.lastname);
    var sex = data[key].sex;
    var age = data[key].age;
    var status = data[key].status;
    Merged.push({name ,sex ,age ,status });
```

enter code here
    }

How do i access a certain element? Example, how do i access row 2 column 2 element?
and what if i want to update a certain row of the element how to do that?

Comment: And? what's the problem?

Comment: What is a firtname?

Comment: Declare your items array outside for loop and with each iteration push values in the item array. It would be better if you store object inside your array, instead of an array inside an array.

Comment: okay. but how do i push elements in the right position of the array? whats the syntax?

Comment: try this `items.push({name, sex, age, status})`, in case you don't want to store object use `items.push({name, sex, age, status})`

Comment: How is PHP involved? This just looks like JavaScript code.

Comment: using push and pop is way better than using conventional for loops?

Comment: sorry about that Don't panic

Comment: hi hassan imam. assuming that im already done with pushing elements. how do i retrieve a certain data in a certain row? lets say first array at column 3. how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd reccomend you use an array of Objects instead:

```
var items = [
  {
    name: "Willy wunka", 
    sex: "M",
    age: "10",
    status: "Married"
  }
];
```

> I'm having a for loop which retrieves data from firebase. ... how do i initialize and store the elements in the array?

```
for(var key in data){
  var name = data[key].revieweeID.firstname.concat(" ",data[key].revieweeID.lastname);
  var sex = data[key].sex;
  var age = data[key].age;
  var status = data[key].status;

  items.push({name, sex, age, status});
}
```

or

```
for(var key in data){
  items.push({
    name: data[key].revieweeID.firstname.concat(" ",data[key].revieweeID.lastname),
    sex: data[key].sex,
    age: data[key].age,
    status: data[key].status
  })
}
```

> how do i access a certain element after pushing

and

> how do i access anelement? like example, element in row 2 at column 2?

you don't have a column `2` anymore. you have a column `age`. The advantage of this is that it is simpler to reason about, even/especially if you ever extend this code.

```
var person = items[2];
console.log(person, person.sex, person.age, person.name);

//since ES6 you can also do 
var {name, sex, age, status} = items[2];
console.log(name, sex, age, status);
```

> what if i want to update array row 1? how do i do that?

I depends on what you mean/want

you can go and change a property of a particular object.

```
person.status = "Single";
```

or you can go and overwrite that index in the list with a new person/object

```
items[0] = {
  name: "John Doe",
  sex: "M",
  age: 99,
  status: "unknown"
};
```

But you should go and learn some basics about `objects` and `references`, in contrast to `primitive values`

Comment: Thank you thomas. uhm can i ask another question? how do i access anelement? like example, element in row 2 at column 2?

Comment: var person=items[2][2]?

Comment: oh! you can use items.("name of the object")

Comment: can i ask one last question thomas? sorry if im annoying you. 
what if i want to update array row 1? how do i do that?

Comment: @WillyWunka I hope, I addressed now all of your questions.

Comment: yes. thank you very much thomas. thank you :). yes i will learn the basiscs :)